# Remove TABLE, TR, TD tags through jquery

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to remove "TABLE, TR, TD" tags through jquery but content shouldn't be deleted inside the table.

i.e. Below is my table code contained images and I want to remove only table, tbody, tr and td tags around the images.

**Code before jquery**

```
<div id="Gallery">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="image1.jpg"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="image2.jpg"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="image3.jpg"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Code should be after jquery**

```
<div id="Gallery">
    <img src="image1.jpg">
    <img src="image2.jpg">
    <img src="image3.jpg">
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
var gallery = $("#Gallery");
var contents = gallery.find("td, th").contents().detach();
gallery.find("table").remove();
gallery.append(contents);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Ydsg9/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#Gallery table').replaceWith(function(){
     return $(this).find('td *');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ec46T/

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#Gallery img").each(function(){
    $("#Gallery").append($(this));
});
$("#Gallery table").remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/jGT5b/

Answer (score 0):

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/Ydsg9/1/)

```
var img = "";
$("td").each(function(){
  img = img + $(this).html();
});

$("#Gallery").append(img);
$("table").remove();
```

Comment: you're missing a `{` after `each(function()` and if corrected it prepends `undefined` to the images

Comment: Using `.html()`, all jQuery event handlers and data are lost

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#Gallery img').unwrap().unwrap().unwrap().unwrap();
```

Comment: Interesting aproach, although not as flexible for other structures.

Answer (score 0):

If you are solely expecting content within the `<td>` elements as you should be, you can use the following:

```
 $(function(){
    var g = $('#Gallery'),
    f = '';

    $('td', g).each(function(){
        f += $(this).html();
    });

    g.html(f);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it

```
        var gallery = $("#Gallery");
        var imgs = $("img", gallery).clone();

        $("table", gallery).remove();
        gallery.append(imgs);
```

the selector is optimized and the `imgs` variable still has a reference to the images inserted in `#Gallery`

Answer (score 0):

Here it is

```
var list = $('#Gallery table td *');
$('#Gallery').html(list.get());
```

You can play with it in here: http://jsfiddle.net/cockypup/Dehgf/2/

The CSS is just to make evident the table is disapearing.